# autoreleasepool error with Xcode5

Tags: ios, objective-c, autorelease

I get 'expected expression' error for below code in Xcode5. I created a command line tool project using Xcode5. Any idea of this error? My build setting does have ARC enabled.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [items addObject:@"One"];
        [items addObject:@"Two"];
        [items addObject:@"Three"];

        [items insertObject:@"Zero" atIndex:0];

        items = nil;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail, such as where and how this code is placed in your project, what compiler you're using, and I'm assuming you just didn't paste the closing brace into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First eliminate the extra "@".

Import Foundation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Next:

```
items = null;
```

replaced the objects added to `items`, is that what you want?
Also `null` is not an Objective-C construct, rather it is an undeclared identifier. Perhaps it should be:

```
items = nil;
```

The following compiles error free:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [items addObject:@"One"];
        [items addObject:@"Two"];
        [items addObject:@"Three"];
        [items insertObject:@"Zero" atIndex:0];
        items = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed extra "@" and set items to nil. Still same issue.

Comment: Add `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`